# Кавычки в начале строки

Tags: пунктуация, typography

Принято ли в русской типографике выносить кавычки за линию абзаца, если кавычки открываются в начале строки?

[image]

Comment: Тут в пункте 14 рекомендуют выносить кавычки за линию набора:
http://lifehacker.ru/2015/08/05/25-pravil-tipografiki/
Однако, типографика это совсем не тема этого сайта.

Comment: @YellowSky спасибо. Есть лучшее место, где можно задать подобный вопрос?

Comment: Ну, наверно, лучше всех [Артемий Лебедев](http://www.artlebedev.ru/) знает.

Comment: Лебедев хвастался когда-то, что они сайты с выносом кавычек за линию набора верстают. Так что Лебедев за вынос кавычек. Вопрос только - это "русская типографика" или "во всем мире так делают". Вот его пост: http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/120/

Comment: @Artemix сойдёт за ответ =)

Comment: спасибо вам за вопрос, обожаю такие.

Comment: Не знаю, что сказано в правилах, если они вообще существуют, но с выносом кавычек текст читается явно проще.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Российская типографика - весьма негреламентированная зона. Типографику можно условно разделить на три этапа (там дальше можно и мельче делить, но основных три). Это дореволюционная, советская и постоветская. Типографика бывает плакатная, газетная, книжная, у каждой немножко свои правила и традиции, это тоже можно иметь ввиду. Так что имейте ввиду, мой ответ упрощенный до предела. Но всё-таки ответ ))

Начнём с дореволюционной. Да, было принято выносить:
[image][image]

Советская типографика и дизайн корнями изначально уходила в дореволюционную - всё, что мы ассоциируем с раннесоветским на самом деле эволюционное продолжение дореволюционного. Даже Окна сатиры РОСТА. Вот, например, раннесоветский плакат (1927-й год):
[image]

Дальше было по-разному, но если упрощать - правило постепенно нарушалось всё чаще и в конце концов перестало быть правилом.

Вот киноплакат 47-го года:

[image]

А вот это уже - 58-й:

[image]

Вот 70-й:

[image]

Сейчас даже занудные пуристы, настаивающие на использование кавычек-ёлочек уже не обращают внимание на подобные нюансы - выравнивают с кавычкой:
[image]
[image]

В целом же это своего рода "левый" аналог (ну или часть её [часть](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanging_punctuation) - это вопрос терминологии) так называемой висячей пунктуации - это когда при выравнивании по правой границе за неё выносятся знаки пунктуации, в том числе и кавычки. Висячая пунктуация используется по факту мало где, но многими людьми, провессионально занимающимися русской типографикой всё-таки считается хорошим тоном в определённых случаях.

Comment: Не думаю, что рекламные плакаты что-то доказывают. У плакатов свои правила. Вероятно, автора вопроса больше интересовали книги и веб.

Comment: @Astronavigator плакаты лишь иллюстрация, короткий ответ - в типографике заголовка считается хорошим тоном, но де-факто очень мало используется, в вебе - в силу технических ограничений - тем более.

Comment: @Astronavigator
Да, меня больше интересует веб, но ответ всё равно интересный. Возник вопрос: нужно ли разделять правила для заголовков и основного текста?

Comment: @Cubius в вебе технически разрешимо, но всё-таки нетривиально так верстать, никто этим попросту не заморачивается. На практике из того что я видел для заголовков такое применялось чаще, что же касается текстов, то чаще соблюдалось по поводу правого края, а с левым реже.